# How do I do that? insert image in code?

Tags: ios

(Please check link first before answer so you can get what i am trying to say)i have [check a code](https://github.com/tstyle/EmoView) in github where in Xcode i found code something like this in this [class](https://github.com/tstyle/EmoView/blob/master/EmoView/Emojis.m) its working great even

```
[[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                      @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"✨", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", nil]retain];
```

**EDIT:-**
How its posible to add images directly as in array or how the Emoji Keyboard enable in Xcode Editor?

Comment: Could you please share that github project.

Comment: Those are not images, those are just parts of the used font.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your question is how to enter Emoji characters into the source code directly:

- In System Preferences -> Keyboard, activate the "Show Keyboard & Character Viewers in menu bar" option.
- Select "Show Character Viewer" from the menu bar.
- If necessary, select "Customize list ..." from the top left popup and activate the "Emoji" category.
- Select the "Emoji" category in the left column.
- Double click on any character to insert it directly into the source code:

[image]

Comment: In Xcode there is a menu entry "Special characters..." accessible via `⎇⌘t`

Comment: @Tassos: Yes, that is what Nitin Gohel said in his answer. I had forgotten about that and his answer is the simpler solution. And the menu entry is available not only in Xcode but also in many other text editors.

Comment: @MartinR Oops, you're right. I should check answers more closely.

Answer (score 4):

This are the Unicode Character. Log that NSArray.

\Ud83d\Ude04 - SMILING FACE WITH OPEN MOUTH AND SMILING EYES

[image]

```
   "\Ud83d\Ude04",
"\Ud83d\Ude0a",
"\Ud83d\Ude03",
"\Ud83d\Ude09",
"\Ud83d\Ude0d",
"\Ud83d\Ude18",
"\Ud83d\Ude1a",
"\Ud83d\Ude33",
"\Ud83d\Ude0c",
"\Ud83d\Ude01",
"\Ud83d\Ude1c",
"\Ud83d\Ude1d",
"\Ud83d\Ude12",
"\Ud83d\Ude0f",
"\Ud83d\Ude13",
"\Ud83d\Ude14",
"\Ud83d\Ude1e",
"\Ud83d\Ude16",
"\Ud83d\Ude25",
"\Ud83d\Ude30",
"\Ud83d\Ude28",
"\Ud83d\Ude23",
"\Ud83d\Ude22",
"\Ud83d\Ude2d",
"\Ud83d\Ude02",
"\Ud83d\Ude32",
"\Ud83d\Ude31",
"\Ud83d\Ude20",
"\Ud83d\Ude21",
"\Ud83d\Ude2a",
"\Ud83d\Ude37",
"\Ud83d\Udc7f",
"\Ud83d\Udc7d",
"\Ud83d\Udc9b",
"\Ud83d\Udc99",
"\Ud83d\Udc9c",
"\Ud83d\Udc97",
"\Ud83d\Udc9a",
"\Ud83d\Udc94",
"\Ud83d\Udc93",
"\Ud83d\Udc98\U2728",
"\Ud83c\Udf1f",
"\Ud83d\Udca4",
"\Ud83c\Udfb5",
"\Ud83d\Udd25",
"\Ud83d\Udca9",
"\Ud83d\Udc4d",
"\Ud83d\Udc4e",
"\Ud83d\Udc4c",
"\Ud83d\Udc9d",
"\Ud83c\Udf8e",
"\Ud83c\Udf92",
"\Ud83c\Udf93",
"\Ud83c\Udf8f",
"\Ud83c\Udf86",
"\Ud83c\Udf83",
"\Ud83c\Udf84",
"\Ud83c\Udf81",
"\Ud83d\Udd14",
"\Ud83d\Udcbf",
"\Ud83d\Udcf7",
"\Ud83d\Udcbb",
"\Ud83d\Udca1"
```

Take a look at [How to enter unicode characters in a UILabel in Interface Builder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11070428/how-to-enter-unicode-characters-in-a-uilabel-in-interface-builder)

> you can click Edit->Special Characters... - there you can find all
>   unicode characters (including the emoji)

Comment: Exactly, it is just part of the font!

Comment: i know its unicodes, but in the githubcode i dont find unicodes any place they directly use icons as an array my question is how they do it?

Comment: Just copy and paste it, like you did.  Or type it using a unicode keyboard, etc.  Though this kind of question is not about programming.

Comment: but is it not sounds wrong ? why a developer use copy and paste every unicode character image in it,if he already know the use of unicodes ?

Comment: How should I know?  I didn't make it!  He probably did it so he could easily access them.

Answer (score 3):

No need to unicode you can simply drag and drop smiley like this:-

see this firt you need to open special Character like bellow image:-

[image]

Then the window open like:-

[image]

Now you just Drage the smily you want to display in array as your question:

```
 [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"",@"✅"nil]retain];
```

Comment: my given answer something different. you can Thru out xocde no need to open system preference as my first screenshot you can directly open special Character from current project xocde.. :) @iphonemaclover

Comment: @NitinGohel: You are right, "Edit -> Special Characters..." is a simpler solution! It is available not only in Xcode but in many other text editors.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> NSArray *arr = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"], nil];
> ```

Comment: no i mean in xcode editor they directly use above code? My question is how they do it? means insert emoji icons in array?