# How to convert numeric input into an NSString containing an umlaut? (etc.)

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, utf

To convert a numeric decimal value x in the range of 97 to 122 into an `NSString` representing that ASCII character, on can simply call:

```
[ NSString stringWithFormat: @"%c", x ]
```

How does one create an NSString for non-ASCII characters such as:

> ä , è , ñ , à , é , ç , ĝ , ŝ , š , ĥ , þ , ð , ĵ , ü , ś , ź , ż

from a strictly numeric input value?  (e.g. decimal `UInt32`, and not copied from or requiring any other `NSString`, Objective-C, or Core Foundation data type in a lookup table).

Is there some online tool that will look up whatever magic decimal numeric values (UTF-foo?) are require for each character?

Comment: Use `%C` instead of `%c`. `%C` supports a bigger range.

Comment: Your question is inconsistent.  If you want the characters without a "lookup table", where do you expect to find your numbers?  I mean you can find the codes in [online tables](http://www.fileformat.info/info/charset/UTF-16/list.htm), but why look them up if you can simply type them into a NSString literal?

Comment: Don't forget part 2: Is there an online utility to lookup the "magic" decimal constants required for %C ?  Or can the lookup be done locally in a web browser using a few lines of javascript?

Comment: @HotLicks: I'm a passing a fixed length numeric value over a hardware link.  8-bit CPU doesn't know NSString literals.

Comment: Then pass the character code.  If you're limited to European languages you can probably get along fine with UTF16 -- 16 bits to the character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the Unicode value then you can do

```
uint32_t code = 0x0125; // U+0125 is 'ĥ'
NSString *s = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:&code length:4 
                            encoding:NSUTF32LittleEndianStringEncoding];
```

This works even for Unicodes outside the "Basic Multilingual Plane", such as

```
uint32_t code = 0x01F604; //  = SMILING FACE WITH OPEN MOUTH AND SMILING EYES
```

The above code assumes that integers are stored in little-endian byte order (which is
the case for all current processors running iOS or OS X). A byte-order independent
method is

```
uint32_t code = OSSwapHostToLittleInt32(0x0125);
```

In Xcode, you can lookup the Unicodes in the "Character Viewer" from the
"Edit -> Special Characters ..." Menu. Of course there are also tables for
all Unicodes at [Unicode 6.3 Character Code Charts](http://www.unicode.org/charts/).

Comment: Or you can just include the character between quotes, in a NSString literal.

Comment: @HotLicks The OP states they have a numeric value that needs to be converted.

Comment: They also said "How does one create an NSString for non-ASCII characters such as:..."

Comment: @hotpaw2: In Xcode, goto "Edit -> Special Characters ...". A character viewer pops up. Choose "Customize List ..." from the top-left pop-up menu. Add "Code Tables -> Unicode". Now select "Unicode" on the left side of the character viewer. (Compare Nitin Gohel's answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17781457/how-do-i-do-that-insert-image-in-code.)

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", ch ];
```

with uppercase %C for unicode characters. See [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html)!

Comment: While I suggested this in a comment, it is important to note that this only works with characters with a Unicode value up to `\UFFFF`. Martin's solution can also handle higher characters.

Comment: @rmaddy I'm sorry, I didn't notice your comment until I finished mine.

Comment: I'm pretty sure, that Martin's uint32_t cannot handle unicode values higher than 0xffff. ;-)

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad: That is interesting, what makes you think that? `0x01F604` is greater than `0xFFFF` and I have tested my code before posting it. (Btw., the largest possible `uint32_t` value is 0xFFFFFFFF`).

Comment: *Boing* Miscounted: 16 instead of 32.