# Unable to display value of M_PI on UILabel swift

Tags: ios, swift, cs193p, xcode6.4

I am following a course CS 193P iPhone Application Development - Stanford University. In Lecture 1 of the tutorial the Same code snippet does not show any error.
I am trying to display the value of M_PI on UILabel in swift for a Calculator project.But it shows an error 'Missing argument label: StringInterpolationSegment' on Line 4. Below is my code snippet.

```
  @IBAction func performOperation(sender:UIButton){

     var mathematicalSymbol  = sender.currentTitle!
     if(mathematicalSymbol == "π"){
       display.text = String(M_PI) //display it the variable for UILabel
     }
}
```

The Function performOperation() is linked to the UIButton with title π.

Comment: Take look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11070469/5654848).

Comment: #Dershwitz123 I want to display the value not the character.

Comment: The above-linked post explains the error, and a simple solution is to use string interpolation: `display.text = "\(M_PI)"` . You may want to employ a formatter to make sure you only display as many digits as you need.

Comment: The linked-to question and its answers are quite old. Actually `display.text = String(M_PI)` should work with the current Xcode 7.3.1. Your Xcode 6.4 is a bit outdated.

Comment: @MartinR so how can do it in Xcode 6.4

Comment: I don't have Xcode 6.4 installed anymore, so I cannot answer that. Are you sure that `let text = String(M_PI)` does not compile? Have you tried `"\(M_PI)"` as suggested in the referenced answers?